# Innerhtml creating textarea field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button with Onclick function. The function should make the text area appear. I cant use the display:none because text area still takes some place on a website when it is not visible

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<textarea></textarea>";
```

Shouldnt this code work properly? it doesnt show anything

Comment: It should work. Check whether function is called for onClick by adding some breakpoints. If you can post more code it'll be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: It should work, but I recommend you not to create element like that, use document.createElement("textarea");

Answer (score 1):

**Old working version**

Well it seems to work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc68a8wb/)

```
<div id="demo"></div>


<script>document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<textarea></textarea>";</script>
```

**Edited version**

Like VMcreator said in the comments, you should use :

```
var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(textarea);
```

Instead of innerHTML.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc68a8wb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var textArea = '<textarea></textarea>';
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textArea;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fLts7xsm/

Comment: Same answer as the first one